# Программа не работает без дополнительного нажатия enter

Tags: python

Осваиваю питон и столкнулся с такой проблемой при использовании конструкции while True, if not s:      break, else
Часть кода после else выполняется только при дополнительном нажатии enter, а как избавиться от этого?

```
d = {}
while True:
    s = input()
    if not s:
        break
    else:
        s = s.split(' ')
        s = ''.join(s)
        ss = s.split(',')
        ss = list(ss)
        for el in ss:
            d[el] = d.get(el, 0) + 1
    print(d)
```

Comment: Ну так убери инпут из цикла. Иначе только с интером

Answer (score 1):

Команда `input()` нужна для того, чтобы пользователь мог ввести свои данные прямо в консоль, а не изменять код каждый раз. После ввода данных, чтобы подтвердить ввод, нужно нажать Enter.
Что касается кода, то как я понял в блоке `else` вы сначала удаляете пробелы, а потом и запятые. Не понятно зачем. Вам следует также показать пример данных, которые вы пытаетесь обрабатывать. Пока вы не предоставите их вам будет трудно помочь, хотя у вас вообще проблема в другом.
Строки:

```
s = s.split(' ')
s = ''.join(s)
```

можно заменить на:

```
s = s.replace(' ', '')
```

Строка:

```
ss = list(ss)
```

совершенно бесполезна. Метод `split()` и так возвращает список.
Больше ничего сказать не могу, пока вы не предоставите пример того, в каком виде у вас вводятся данные.

Comment: С клавиатуры ввожу слова через запятую с пробелом. на выходе должен получить словарь, в котором ключами будут встреченные слова, а значениями - их количество в строке.
Форма ввода asd, asdfg, asdfg